# Run script on files in all levels of sub directories

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script written in bash to convert flac files in a folder. However, it doesn't work if the files are in a sub directory of the folder I'm calling.

For example, if I call a directory that has the flac files directly in it, the script works fine.  If there are folders between the folder called and the flac files, it wont run.

- `AlbumName/*.flac`   <-- runs fine when calling `AlbumName`
- `AlbumName/CD1/*.flac`   <-- wont run when calling `AlbumName`

Here is the code I'm using:

```
for file in "$1"/*.flac
do
    if [ -f "${file}" ]; then

        # do flac conversion script

    fi
done
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: what does flac conversion involves in layman terms? it seems that `find` could handle that job better. something among these lines: `find . -name "*$1/*.flac" -type f -exec flac_conversion {} \;`

Comment: it makes a new folder with the basename from the called folder, changes the "FLAC" in the folder name to "V0", then it runs a flac to mp3 converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get all `.flac` files with `find` and then execute the flac conversion script with each one of them passed as argument:

```
find . -path "*.flac" -type f -exec ./flac_converter.sh "{}" \;
```

this command finds every file (`-type f`) in path `.` that matches `*.flac` at the end of the string, then executes `-exec flac_converter.sh` with each match `{}`.

so for example if i have this file structure:

```
$ tree flacs
flacs
    ├── asd.flac
    ├── dsa.flac
    └── more
        └── more_asd.flac
```

running that command will produce:

```
$ find . -path "*.flac" -type f -exec ./flac_converter.sh "{}" \;
I'm converting ./flacs/asd.flac
I'm converting ./flacs/dsa.flac
I'm converting ./flacs/more/more_asd.flac
```

`flac_converter.sh` only echoes that sentence with `$1` (the file from `find` as input). notice that it runs `./flacs/more/*.flac` as well as `./flacs/*.flac` smoothly.